# Proving a limit of a Markov process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

> Let $\{X_{t}\}$ be a continuous time Markov process with a phase space
>   consisting of only two states from the set $S = \{1, 2 \}$. Let $1 -
>  p_{ii}(t) = q_{i}(t) + o(t)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, where $i \in S$ and
>   $0 < q_{i} < \infty$.
>
> $1)$ Prove that $\{X_{t}\}$ has a unique stationary distribution and find it.
>
> $2)$ Let $(r_{1}(0), r_{2}(0))$ be the intial distribution of the process $r_{i}(0) = P\{X_{0} = i\}$, $i \in S$; $r_{i}(t) = P\{X_{t} = i\}$, $t \geq 0$. Prove 
>   $$\lim_{t\to\infty} r_{j}(t) = \overline{r}_{j},$$
>   where $j \in S$

I think I am doing $(1)$ correctly. I am setting up a matrix system of two equations, whose solution is always unique. So, we can conclude it has a unique stationary distribution.

I have no idea how to approach $(2)$, though. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is $q_i$ and how does it relate to $q_i(t)$?

Comment: Hmm, this is what the problem has given me. I would guess that the inequality meant to say $0 < q_{i}(t) < \infty$, since that would make more sense?

Comment: I just realized that they do not mean $q_i(t)$ to be a function of $t$, they mean a multiplication of $q_i$ and $t$. (At least, this is the only interpretation that makes sense.) This is a system with fixed transition rates $\mu_{12} = q_1, \mu_{21} = q_2$. That equation is supposed to be $$ P[X_t=i|X_0=i] = 1-tq_i + o(t)$$ where $o(t)$ is an error term that satisfies $\lim_{t\rightarrow0} o(t)/t=0$. So this is just an ordinary CTMC with 2 states.  You can use the above  equation in a differential equation approach, or you can just use a basic steady state theorem for CTMCs.

Comment: Do you mean the forward/backward kolmogorov equations? I am not getting anywhere with those, unfortunately

Comment: You do $$P[X(t+\delta)=1] = P[X(t+\delta)=1|X(t)=2]P[X(t)=2] + P[X(t+\delta)=1|X(t)=1]P[X(t)=1]$$ to get a linear ODE for $r_1(t)$. The stationary part comes by setting $r_1'(t)=0$ and the limiting part comes by just solving the ODE.

Comment: I have already found the stationary distribution by doing $\pi Q = 0$, but I'm having trouble with the differential equation part. Can you please help me?

Comment: I thought we do Chapman-Kolmogorov for the limiting part?

Comment: What is troubling you on working out the next steps of my prior comment?

Comment: I don't understand how to actually get the ODE. Right now, it just seems like a conditioned probability. Also, I'm assuming $\delta$ is just a really small positive number?

Comment: Yes, note the left-hand-side is $r_1(t+\delta)$ and the right-hand-side can be written in terms of $r_1(t)$, $q_1, q_2$, $\delta$, and $o(\delta)$.  You let $\delta\rightarrow 0$ and use the definition of derivative.